# Plotting relatively large networks in R with igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have two questions, the first is more complicated than the second.

1. I have a plot of my network below, but the plot is rather clustered how can I spread the nodes out more so I can clearly see the edges. I've tried a circular plot but I still got a rather clustered plot.
2. How can I rename the nodes? The current plot puts an 'X' in front of the node name, how can I remove the 'X'?

In my matrix an interacting node is marked with `1`, non interacting nodes are marked with `0`

[image]

Code:

```
library(igraph)

df <- as.matrix(read.table("sig_pairs_matrix_for_r.txt"))

g=graph.adjacency(df,mode="undirected",weighted=NULL,diag=FALSE) 
plot.igraph(g,vertex.label=V(g)$name)
```

Matrix:

```
     4   6   7   8  12  13  15  17  22  23  25  26  27  29  30  31  34  35  36  43  44  47  48  52  53  56  57  59  63  66  67  70  96  99 122 166 168 172 174 176 180 181 191 192 193 220 222 224 225 226 236 249 253 256 258 266 267 277 296
  4  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  6  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  7  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  8  0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 12  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 13  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 17  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 22  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 25  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 26  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 27  0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 29  0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 30  0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 31  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 34  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 35  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 36  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 43  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 44  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 47  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 48  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 52  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 53  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 56  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 57  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 59  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 63  0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 66  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 67  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 70  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 96  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 99  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
122  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
166  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
168  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
172  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
174  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
176  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
180  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
181  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
191  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
192  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
193  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
220  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
222  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
224  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
225  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
226  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
236  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
249  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
253  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0
256  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
258  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
266  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
267  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
277  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
296  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: It would help if you could make your data available in a more "paste-into-R-friendly" way. You could use `dput` for this.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, check `?igraph::layout`. There's some instructions how you can alter the aligment of nodes.

For your second question, I guess the graph takes the names of the nodes from the row or column names of your matrix but `read.table` by default appends names with prefix X in order to make names starting with number valid variable names (see `make.names`). So rownames of your matrix are actually X1, X2 etc. You can circumvent this by reading your matrix like this:

```
df <- as.matrix(read.table("sig_pairs_matrix_for_r.txt",check.names=FALSE))
```

Or you could rename the rows and columns of your matrix before making the graph, i.e.

```
#newnames is a vector containing the new names, such as c("a","b",...)
rownames(df)<-colnames(df)<-newnames
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question I would create a separate files for the row and column names. Once imported you can set the column and row names.

```
temp = read.csv("adj_matrix.csv", sep=",",head=FALSE)
adjmatrix <- as.matrix(temp)

temprow = read.csv("rownames.csv", sep=",",head=FALSE)
rowns <-as.matrix(temprow)

tempcol = read.csv("colnames.csv", sep=",",head=FALSE)
cols <-as.matrix(tempcol)

rownames(adjmatrix)<- rows
colnames(adjmatrix)<- cols

g1 <- graph.adjacency(adjmatrix, mode=c("directed"), weighted=NULL, diag=TRUE)
plot.igraph(g1)
```